# Python: How to use a figure defined in a function outside the function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, figure

I have this code:

```
def functionPlot():
    ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([1,1])
    return ax

if __name__=="__main__":
   ax=functionPlot()
```

I would like to get the figure defined inside the function "functionPlot" to be used in the "main" function. 
I am not being able to that. 
How can I do that? What should I return from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def functionPlot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([1,1])
    return fig

if __name__=="__main__":
    fig = functionPlot()
    # do other things with fig
```